# ASP.Net MVC Actionlink/Url action for javascript table - datatable.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using the jquery datatable to render my html table using the server side option. One of the columns on the table has a url/"edit" link for the respective row. I'm able to generate this using the following code :

```
{
    "data": "Id",
    "title": "Linked Accounts",
    "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return '<a href=\"LinkedAccountsDetails/' + data + '\">Edit</a>';
    }

}
```

However I am unable to generate this using a Html.Actionlink or url action with a route value. I.e. the data parameter from the javascript function to be used as a route value. Is this possible and can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

```
  "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        //return '<a href=\"LinkedAccountsDetails/' + data + '\">Edit</a>';
                        var myUrl = '@Url.Action("LinkedAccountsDetails", "Profile")/' + data;
                        return '<a href=\"'+myUrl+'\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\">Edit</a>'; 

                    }
```

This appears to have solved the issue. Thanks to those who took the time to look at the question.